# How to get connection status on a BLE device in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware

I have a Bluetooth low-energy device paired to my Windows 10 machine, when an application try to use it, Windows automatically connects the paired device. I want to be able to read if the device is connected or just paired to Windows. Searching around Window's Device Manager (accessible from Control Panel), I saw that the device had the property "Is connected" under the details tab, it's value (true/false) was changing accordingly to the actual device status.

I tried to read to access this property using the `SetupDiGetDeviceProperty` function with the `DEVPKEY_DeviceContainer_IsConnected` predefined key but for some reason I get ERROR_NOT_FOUND.

Any ideas?

Comment: Microsoft uses WinSock to communicate with [Bluetooth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362932.aspx) devices and expose information about them. You can use `WSALookupServiceBegin/Next()` to enumerate known devices and get connection status info. [Bluetooth and WSAQUERYSET for Device Inquiry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362918.aspx)

Comment: You can also use [`BluetoothFindFirstRadio()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362786.aspx) and [`BluetoothGetDeviceInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362795.aspx) to enumerate Bluetooth devices and get their connection states.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I do not use winsocks to communicate with a bluetooth *low-energy* device, I use GATT/ATT. And the functions you gave me in the second comment, according to my understanding, are intended to work with Bluetooth devices and not Bluetooth *low-energy* (or BLE) devices.